# Selection Sort Algorithm swaps

Tags: sorting

> I use Selection Sort to sort 100 reverse-sorted integers {100,99,98...1}. How  many 'useless' swaps will our selection sort perform? A useless swap is where the array contents are unchanged because a value is swapped with itself.

To me the answer looks like zero? Because after each iteration of selection sort, I have the following: {1 99 98 .... 4 3 2 100}
                      {1 2 98 ..... 4 3 99 100} and so on

However, the answer is 50. How is that possible?

Comment: Are you sure that the question is not asking you to produce a reverse sorted list from a reverse sorted list?

Comment: Yeah, could be it. In which case the answer would be 50.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning that it should be zero useless swaps if you are reversing the order of the list, and your defense of this reasoning is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following list

**5 4 3 2 1**

1 **4 3 2 5** //swap 1 with 5

1 2 **3 4 5** //swap 2 with 4

1 2 3 **4 5** //useless swap (3 with 3)

1 2 3 4 **5** //useless swap (4 with 4)

now apply this on your list.

Answer (score 0):

The last swap will be 50 and 51. Once this swap is done, all other elements are swapped. So swaps will be 1-100,2-99,3-98.....,48-53,49-52,50-51...
This completes the sorting. After 50 swaps, rest all elements are automatically sorted. So rest of the swaps are useless.